# Which software to use for RAMDISK on Windows 2008?

Tags: windows-server-2008, ramdisk

I am building a server machine with lots of RAM. At least 16G. I am planning to put my frequently read and written data in RAM so I am looking for software for creating RAM disks. This is for Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard 64bit.

Any recommendations? I would like one where I can flush the disk image into persistent storage upon demand. For example when Windows shuts down.

(I am aware of all the consequences of data loss when power is lost)

Answer (score 3):

"Just dont": FIrst, 16gb is a low end RAM those days. Still, WIndows uses RAM as cache anyway - so unless you put some temp stuff there that has a lot of IO - nothing is gained.

Comment: +1. Windows will cache frequently accessed data in RAM anyway, there's no need to come up with elaborate hacks to get what you want.

Comment: If I have thousands of files used by IIS and they are read several hundred times a day, Windows will put all these files in RAM, as long as memory allows?

Comment: No, IIS does not. WINDOWS FILE CACHING does. THis is not an IIS function - but windows is pretty good at caching to start with. Just make sure it has enough RAM for that (I.e. not used by IIS etc.)